# Running two algorithms with the same data input in java

Tags: java, algorithm, guava

I am thinkink for two days for a solution technique for my problem.But I still fail.
In main method,I am randomly generating Guava Table values which are list of integers.

I want two write this table values into a file and then read values from two algorithms to process these values.The readed values will also be stored into tables which will be created in these two algorithms.

My aim is testing or comparing two algorithms with the same (generated)data input.

What I want to ask is how structure or class mechanism should I have ?

Importantly I feel the need of saying that I am not doing comparison of time efficiency or space complexity. Algorithms are about optimization problems.

Comment: I'd say "We need more information™". From the description alone I don't even get what you're asking about. "how structure or class mechanism should I have?" - A structure for what? Reading/writing the file? Holding values? Comparing your algorithms? (I guess "class mechanism" is meant to be the same as "structure" here).

Comment: Show us what you tried so far. As, so far, you only provided some vague requirements ... but sorry, this is not a "we design your solution for you" service. We help with specific questions about programming; not about "me vision, but no idea, please fill that gap" kind of input. If at all, I would be looking into such things like the **strategy** pattern.

Comment: Thank you, I am asking how can I compare algorihms? Should I write my algorithms in different classes and call these classes in another class which has main method ?

Comment: @GhostCat A sample execution output of my code as follows:

Comment: Hint: you **never** put more infos into answer/comments; you put it into the **question**.

Comment: There's [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/42554998/581205) by the OP, which is a bit clearer, so I guess, this one can go.