# writing guava table values into file in java

Tags: java, file-io, guava

How to write Guava table into a file ?
What is the best way of doing this ?
It is not important how values seems in table. My primary aim writing and reading table.

Answer (score 2):

There are various ways to model a table for persistence and different approaches are better for different types of tables (e.g. dense vs parse, array table vs tree based table, etc.).

For a general purpose (i.e. not optimized for any particular type of table) I would probably persist the following:

1. an array of the row keys
2. an array of the column keys
3. an array of cells where each cell contains the following:

   1. the index of its row key in the array of the row keys
   2. the index of its column key in the array of the column keys
   3. the value

With that in mind you can accomplish such using [google/gson: A Java serialization/deserialization library that can convert Java Objects into JSON and back.](https://github.com/google/gson)

Example:

```
class TableTypeHierarchyAdapter<R, C, V> implements JsonSerializer<Table<R, C, V>>, JsonDeserializer<Table<R, C, V>> {
    @Override
    public JsonElement serialize(Table<R, C, V> src, Type typeOfSrc, JsonSerializationContext context) {
        JsonArray rowKeysJsonArray = new JsonArray();
        Map<R, Integer> rowKeyToIndex = new HashMap<>();
        for (R rowKey : src.rowKeySet()) {
            rowKeyToIndex.put(rowKey, rowKeyToIndex.size());
            rowKeysJsonArray.add(context.serialize(rowKey));
        }
        JsonArray columnKeysJsonArray = new JsonArray();
        Map<C, Integer> columnKeyToIndex = new HashMap<>();
        for (C columnKey : src.columnKeySet()) {
            columnKeyToIndex.put(columnKey, columnKeyToIndex.size());
            columnKeysJsonArray.add(context.serialize(columnKey));
        }
        JsonArray cellsJsonArray = new JsonArray();
        for (Table.Cell<R, C, V> cell : src.cellSet()) {
            JsonObject cellJsonObject = new JsonObject();
            int rowIndex = rowKeyToIndex.get(cell.getRowKey());
            int columnIndex = columnKeyToIndex.get(cell.getColumnKey());
            cellJsonObject.addProperty("rowIndex", rowIndex);
            cellJsonObject.addProperty("columnIndex", columnIndex);
            cellJsonObject.add("value", context.serialize(cell.getValue()));
            cellsJsonArray.add(cellJsonObject);
        }
        JsonObject tableJsonObject = new JsonObject();
        tableJsonObject.add("rowKeys", rowKeysJsonArray);
        tableJsonObject.add("columnKeys", columnKeysJsonArray);
        tableJsonObject.add("cells", cellsJsonArray);
        return tableJsonObject;
    }

    @Override
    public Table<R, C, V> deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) {
        Type typeOfR;
        Type typeOfC;
        Type typeOfV;
        {
            ParameterizedType parameterizedType = (ParameterizedType) typeOfT;
            Type[] actualTypeArguments = parameterizedType.getActualTypeArguments();
            typeOfR = actualTypeArguments[0];
            typeOfC = actualTypeArguments[1];
            typeOfV = actualTypeArguments[2];
        }
        JsonObject tableJsonObject = json.getAsJsonObject();
        JsonArray rowKeysJsonArray = tableJsonObject.getAsJsonArray("rowKeys");
        Map<Integer, R> rowIndexToKey = new HashMap<>();
        for (JsonElement jsonElement : rowKeysJsonArray) {
            R rowKey = context.deserialize(jsonElement, typeOfR);
            rowIndexToKey.put(rowIndexToKey.size(), rowKey);
        }
        JsonArray columnKeysJsonArray = tableJsonObject.getAsJsonArray("columnKeys");
        Map<Integer, C> columnIndexToKey = new HashMap<>();
        for (JsonElement jsonElement : columnKeysJsonArray) {
            C columnKey = context.deserialize(jsonElement, typeOfC);
            columnIndexToKey.put(columnIndexToKey.size(), columnKey);
        }
        JsonArray cellsJsonArray = tableJsonObject.getAsJsonArray("cells");
        ImmutableTable.Builder<R, C, V> builder = ImmutableTable.builder();
        for (JsonElement jsonElement : cellsJsonArray) {
            JsonObject cellJsonObject = jsonElement.getAsJsonObject();
            int rowIndex = cellJsonObject.get("rowIndex").getAsInt();
            int columnIndex = cellJsonObject.get("columnIndex").getAsInt();
            R rowKey = rowIndexToKey.get(rowIndex);
            C columnKey = columnIndexToKey.get(columnIndex);
            V value = context.deserialize(cellJsonObject.get("value"), typeOfV);
            builder.put(rowKey, columnKey, value);
        }
        return builder.build();
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
Table<String, String, String> table = ImmutableTable.<String, String, String>builder()
        .put("R1", "C1", "R1C1")
        .put("R1", "C2", "R1C2")
        .put("R2", "C1", "R2C1")
        .put("R2", "C2", "R2C2")
        .build();
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
        .setPrettyPrinting()
        .registerTypeHierarchyAdapter(Table.class, new TableTypeHierarchyAdapter())
        .create();
try (FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("table.json")) {
    gson.toJson(table, writer);
}
try (FileReader reader = new FileReader("table.json")) {
    Type typeOfTable = new TypeToken<Table<String, String, String>>() {}.getType();
    Table<String, String, String> readTable = gson.fromJson(reader, typeOfTable);
    assert table.equals(readTable);
}
```

table.json:

```
{
  "rowKeys": [
    "R1",
    "R2"
  ],
  "columnKeys": [
    "C1",
    "C2"
  ],
  "cells": [
    {
      "rowIndex": 0,
      "columnIndex": 0,
      "value": "R1C1"
    },
    {
      "rowIndex": 0,
      "columnIndex": 1,
      "value": "R1C2"
    },
    {
      "rowIndex": 1,
      "columnIndex": 0,
      "value": "R2C1"
    },
    {
      "rowIndex": 1,
      "columnIndex": 1,
      "value": "R2C2"
    }
  ]
}
```